# Google App Script URLFetch quota not clear

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, urlfetch

I'm interested of building a spreadsheet add-on that relies on external services and it seems that URLFetch is the only way of performing remote HTTP/S calls with app script.

I've reached the [app script quota page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) to check limitations and I can see that they are

- 100.000 calls/day for GSuite plans
- 20.000 calls/day for Gmail plans

What is not clear from the documentation is if these limits are related to the whole application or just the single user installation of the add-on / application.

Also the documentation doesn't really explain if there's any way to can ask google for increased quotas for a specific application, something that you might need and do in GCP for specific apis for example.

Anybody with app script experience and with a published add-on can share some light to it ? Has anyone attempt to create a app-script that heavily uses external services ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Apps Script quota apply per user invoking a service.

i.e. if each user of the application calls a service on his own behalf - each user will have awarded the quota mentioned in the documentation.

On the contrary, if you are using a service account that performs a call on behalf of a user without impersonating him - all calls from all users will count against the service account quota.

As for API quotas, they apply per project. You can consult [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) how to request an increase of quota.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, have you by any change found the page of the documentation where this is mentioned ? Also do you know if this still applies for triggers and during the execution of app script execution apis ?

Comment: Not directly, you can kind of retrieve it from `Quotas are set at different levels for users `, `Script invoked too many times per second for this Google user account` etc., I gained the certainty through trying it out...

Comment: Yeah, I also think this is the idea they want to give you in the page when they separate between Current quotas and Current limitations, but it still feels odd that there's no a precise statement about this. I'm now developing a simple script to reach the limit with one user, then I'll execute it with another user and see what's the result :) Just want to be 100% sure about this

Comment: So I've tested with my script as promised and as you said those limits are applied as a per-user basis. This is great news :) Thank you again !